# What is Django ORM equivalent of SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=somestring?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, sqlite, django-orm

**Model**

```
class ShowDetail(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SeasonDetail(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(ShowDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class EpisodeDetail(models.Model):
    showTitle = models.ForeignKey(ShowDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seasonNumber = models.ForeignKey(SeasonDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    episodeTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    episodeNumber = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

**Logic**

```
episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(title=showname).values('season')
```

I want to check the season value (01, 02, 03 etc) are present for given tv-show (Arrow, The Flash etc).

I am getting below error, when I try to update the season value in EpisodeDetail model:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'The Flash'
```

When I am using

```
episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(title=showname).values_list('season', flat=True)
```

Getting error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'The Flash'
```

And when I use

```
episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(title=ShowDetail.objects.get(title=showname)).values_list('season', flat=True)
```

I am getting

```
Cannot assign "['01']": "EpisodeDetail.seasonNumber" must be a "SeasonDetail" instance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) queryset method.

```
YouModel.objects.filter(col2=something).values('col1')
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want a raw representation, you need to use `values_list` along `flat=True`

```
YouModel.objects.filter(title=showname).values_list('season',flat=True)
```

This returns

```
[01, 02, 03,....]
```

**UPDATE 2**
In your model `seasonNumber` is a foreign key to a SeasonDetail instance, you are trying to assign a list.  So, remove the `value_list()` and get the first one.

```
episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(title=showname)[0]
```

Comment: that did not work, i have added the details in the question. please advise or let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: @sid8491 Updated it. Check it.

Comment: still getting same error :
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'The Flash'

if I use 
episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(title=ShowDetail.objects.get(title=showname)).values_list('season', flat=True)
then I am getting below error :
Cannot assign "['01']": "EpisodeDetail.seasonNumber" must be a "SeasonDetail" instance.

Comment: thanks, its working with below code:

episode_update.seasonNumber = SeasonDetail.objects.filter(season=str(i).zfill(2))[0]

Answer (score 0):

With django version >=1.8: use the values_list

## You can access list of column.

```
YourModel.objects.values_list('col1', 'col2')
```

You can also use:-

`QuerySet.only()` and `QuerySet.defer()` can be used to define which fields the ORM query should fetch and defer the others until the appropriate attributes on the models are accessed.

Comment: that did not work, i have added the details in the question. please advise or let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: I think you are passing 'The flash' to seasonNumber but it required IntegerNumber. 01 or 02.